# How i can return a std::map containing the differences of two maps in c++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

i have two maps and i need to find the differences and create a new map that only has the differences. Not sure how to do this. I tried using set_difference but don't really understand how it works. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

```
// header file
typedef std::map<std::string, int> MapCol;
typedef std::map<std::string, MapCol> MapRow;
MapRow m_mapRows;

//.cpp fle
CheckForDifferences( const Table& rhs )
{
    Table diffTable;
    vector<string> v;                           
    vector<string>::iterator it;
    it=set_difference (m_mapRows.begin(), m_mapRows.end(), diffTable.m_mapRows.begin(), diffTable.m_mapRows.end, v.begin());
}
```

edit:

```
std::set_difference( m_mapRows.begin(), m_mapRows.end(),
rhs.m_mapRows.begin(), rhs.m_mapRows.end(), diffTable.m_mapRows.begin());
```

ok this is what i tried, but i get errors, the first one being
 error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by difference? set_difference is  a well defined process but on sets.

Comment: For a reference, see e.g. [std::set_difference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) and [std::set_symmetric_difference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference)

Comment: As Mark points out this will depend greately on what you mean by *difference* (i.e. same key different value are the same or different entries?). From the code it seems that you are only concerned on the keys, and not the values (you are inserting into a `vector<string>`). It seems that in your particular case it might be simpler to just implement a loop that does your difference-transformation as operation chaining is not really well supported in the standard library.

Comment: Ideally i would like to check on both the key and the value, but just checking if the value has changed and creating a new map of only the values that changed from the first map to the second map

Comment: What error do you get? What is `Table`? Please provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5):

If you have two sorted containers `a` and `b` and you want to copy the set of objects that aren't in either one into another container `c`, you'd do this:

```
std::set_symmetric_difference(
    a.begin(), a.end(),
    b.begin(), b.end(),
    std::back_inserter(c) );
```

If you just want the elements from `a` that aren't in `b`, use `set_difference` instead of `set_symmetric_difference`.

Comment: That should work, but the asker is trying to perform this operation on a jagged map and some unknown type `Table`. Apples and Oranges...

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
std::set_difference( m_mapRows.begin(), m_mapRows.end(),
rhs.m_mapRows.begin(), rhs.m_mapRows.end(), diffTable.m_mapRows.begin());
```

you try to use regular iterator as output, that does not work. In your case you can use [std::inserter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter)

```
std::set_difference( m_mapRows.begin(), m_mapRows.end(),
rhs.m_mapRows.begin(), rhs.m_mapRows.end(), std::inserter( diffTable.m_mapRows, diffTable.m_mapRows.begin()));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my take on it. Very basic. You start off from a copy of the left hand operand and remove all that is present in the right hand operand.
It leaves you with the difference as defined by set theory.

```
template< class TMap >
auto    MapDiff( const TMap & lh, const TMap & rh )
{
  auto result = lh ;

  for( auto const & item : rh )
  {
    result.erase( item.first ) ;
  }

  return result ;
}
```