# How to compare two maps by both key and value and storing difference map in resultant map in c++? Do we have any stl api for it?

Tags: c++, stl

Do we have any stl function to compare and store difference between map like set_difference or is there a way to use set_difference?
If anyone has a logic to compare both value or key of two maps with less complexity will be much appreciated.
Note: Using C++

Comment: You mentioned `set_difference`. Did you try it? Please explain how the results from `set_difference` is not what you expected.

Comment: `std::set_difference` compares whatever dereferenced iterators return. In case of `std::map`, this is a pair of key and value, so these pairs, i.e., both keys and values, are compared. Is this what you want?

Comment: You supply your own comparator function / lambda and pipe it down the `std::set_difference` route.

Comment: `std::set_difference` is not just for `std::set`  It will work with any contain/iterator combination that satisfies the pre-conditions.

Comment: Is this a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201463/how-i-can-return-a-stdmap-containing-the-differences-of-two-maps-in-c ?

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, double> square    = {{0, 0.0}, {1, 1.0}, {2, 4.0}};
    std::map<int, double> fibonacci = {{0, 0.0}, {1, 1.0}, {2, 1.0}};
    std::vector<std::pair<int, double>> result;
    std::set_difference(begin(square), end(square), begin(fibonacci), end(fibonacci), std::back_inserter(result));

    for (auto p : result) {
        std::cout << p.first << " => " << p.second << "\n";
    }
    // prints 2 => 4 as expected
}
```

`std::set_difference` is perfectly usable with `std::map`. Full demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02cc424fa0e5aba0

---

And for fun:

```
template<class Container>
auto operator-(Container lhs, Container rhs)
{
    std::vector<typename Container::value_type> result;
    std::set_difference(cbegin(lhs), cend(lhs), cbegin(rhs), cend(rhs), std::back_inserter(result));
    return result;
}
auto result = square - fibonacci;
```

Comment: Do you really want to pass `lhs` and `rhs` for fun by value? ;-)

Comment: This is a special form of gvalue: the [funvalue](https://web.archive.org/web/20140205194657/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/).

Comment: Don't see your point. Lvalue arguments (`square` and `fibonacci`), will always be copied into operator parameters (`lhs` and `rhs`) here. These copies cannot be elided.

Comment: @DanielLangr it's because I meant `cbegin` and typed `begin`, my bad. https://godbolt.org/g/9XjpiW

Comment: If you does sorting on lhs/rhs, it would make sense, currently using const ref avoid any copies [Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/zVD1Tf).